# include ReadMe.md, convert to markdown and include in html

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I am writting a github gh-page `index.html`:

Is it possible with some javascript, to import the `ReadMe.md` from a link and send it to the markdown javascript formatter ([i think thats the file](https://assets-cdn.github.com/javascripts/ace/mode/markdown.js)) of github and append the output somewhere in the  `index.html`?

I am new to javascript and html.